# Uml uses case diagram suggestion

Tags: uml

Hi i am currently drawing a UML use case diagram of my app, and I want to know if it is correct or not. My use case is managing arrived mails in mail manager app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.

- `Login` is no use case at all. It's a constraint that applies to certain UCs.
- The Generalization relations are all wrong and make no sense.
- The relation between `Bo`and `cbo` is unclear as the label obfuscates the triangle which I suppose is a Generalization (which might make sense).
- A generalization for actors makes just sense if they have different UCs.
- The extensive (and likely wrong) use of `<<extend>>` relations indicates that you are actually trying functional decomposition. UCs are about added value, not about functions.
- There are unmotivated swim lanes.

Think about what the real added value of your app is. `Manage mail` is definitely not a real big one (it's too obvious). Something like `Find mail by keyword` would be something, I guess.